# Fetching the text box value from view to controller in php

Tags: php, html

how to fetch the text box values from input textbox that is in view page to the controller in php and display..

**VIEW**

```
 <input type="text" name="Quantity" id="Quantity" value="" />
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
       function cartoutput()
  {//echo "hi";
$category = $this->input->post('Category');
$num = $this->input->post('numOflimit');
$productName    =   $this->input->post('product_name');
$barcode    =   $this->input->post('barcode');
$quantity   =   $this->input->post('Quantity');
echo $quantity;

for ($x=1;$x<=$num;$x++)
        {
            $userArray  =   $_POST["select".$x.""];
            echo $userArray;
            //echo $quantity;
            if ($userArray!="") 
            {
                $userArray = split(',',$userArray);
            //echo $userArray;
                $productName            =   $userArray[0];
                $barcode                =   $userArray[1];
                 $quantity              =   $userArray[2];
                $flag   =   $this->cartmodel->getProductNames($category);
                //print_r($quantity);
            }
        }
```

}
  }

Comment: You should at least provide the structure of your Controller-View

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is a poorly worded question, you'll need to provide more information about what you want.

To fetch values from an input textbox, use the `$_POST` method on the HTML form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="my-textbox"/>
</form>
```

Then, to fetch the values from the controller and display it:

```
if(isset($_POST['my-textbox'])){
    echo $_POST['my-textbox'];
}
```

Obviously, you'd want to sanitize the `$_POST` string before you do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Its same as input text just put atribute name="textboxname" in it and $_POST/$_GET['textboxname'] but dont forget to use form tag.

```
HTML 


<form action="script.php" method="post/get">
    <textarea name="textboxname"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP script.php

```
if($_POST/GET['submit']){
     $text = $_POST/GET['textboxname'];
     echo $text;
   }
```